# Blazor ReactiveUI MVVM - Resolving the dependency in ViewModel

Tags: c#, mvvm, dependency-injection, blazor, reactiveui

I'm using Blazor WebAssembly and ReactiveUI MVVM in an application and trying to invoke a JavaScript function from the ViewModel. I'm getting runtime null exception because the JsRuntime property is not injected.

```
public class TestViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    [Inject]
    IJSRuntime JsRuntime { get; set; }

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        AlertCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(ShowAlertMessage);
    }

    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> PopulateCommand { get; }


    public void ShowAlertMessage()
    {
        JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("showAlert", "Hello World!");
    }
}
```

I tried with the constructor injection as well a no success.
How can I call a JavaScript function from the ViewModel?

Comment: I would use a Interaction then use a page view to show the massage personally. The Inject stuff would want a page where it knows the lifetime

Comment: @GlennWatson you mean writing the code in view instead view model? can you please elaborate your comment?

Comment: Use a Interaction https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/interactions/ to run that JavaScript on the view.

Comment: Instead of using Interactions, another approach would be to use HanumanInstitute.MvvmDialogs. The Blazor implementation hasn't been done yet but should not be too hard to implement (copying from Avalonia code). Much simpler and cleaner than ReactiveUI interactions.
https://github.com/mysteryx93/HanumanInstitute.MvvmDialogs